# asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview which contains columns of my desire to display. But I want to access a value for data row of a gridview which is not displayed in gridview but it is in datatable for that particular row.
Initially what I did is display it to gridview as well as I accessed its value using index, but I really don't want to display its value in gridview. In that case I set visible=false but then it doesn't recognize to cell so what should I do to achieve this?
Please let me know so that I don't have to display that particular row and I can access the value for that row which do exist in data table.

Comment: What do you plan to do with that value? Can you store the value in a cookie?

Comment: Your question is unclear as to whether you are talking about a column you don't want displayed, or a completely separate row of data.  Clarify please?

Answer (score 1):

You can access all column values if you set their visible="false" , In this situation You need to set datakey name for your gridview .

```
    //In GridView RowCommand Event:
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

    //If we have more than one DataKeys ( ItemId is the field that is visbile = false and myGridView.DatakeyName = Itemid)
    int ItemId = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[index].Values["ItemId"]);
    //else
    int ItemId = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value);
```

If your desired column is not datakey , So you can use gridViewRow

```
  GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
```

and Then you can access all the column of that row .

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use this for something like a primary key from the table?  Here's a blog post I wrote a couple years ago that explains how you can leverage a field like this from the database without it displaying.  The gist of it is that you should look into using **DataKeys**.

[Using a Primary Key with ASP.NET Data Controls](http://rchern.wordpress.com/2008/04/27/using-a-primary-key-with-aspnet-data-controls/)